# How to find total numbers of all minimum path between s and t through v in a graph?

Tags: graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I want to find total number of all minimum path between s and t through v in a graph, where s,t and v are nodes of the graph, by using Floyd Warshall algorithm.
Thanks in advance for yours answers.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the number of shortest paths between s and v with floyd-warshall, then find all shortest path from v to t and then multiple the result. for instance, if there are 3 shortest paths between s and v, 2 shortest path from v to t then there 6 shortest paths from s to t through v.

Comment: for example, if i have an oriented complete graph, when i have to calculate the number of shortest path with v = 0 and i = 1 and j = 2 before "i" is increased i have a minumum of 98 path?

    int i, j, v;
 int ris = 0;
 for (v = 0; v < n_nodi; v++) {
  for (i = 0; i < n_nodi; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < n_nodi; j++) {
    if (i != j && i != v && j != v) {
        ris += (graph[i][v] * graph[v][j]);

    }
   }
  }
}

thank you very much for your availability

Comment: you can search about floyd-warshall implementation in your desire language and then as I said, calculate number of path between s,v and v,t then multiple them.